# Iterar un Query para reemplazar datos

Tags: mysql, sql, iteradores

tengo una duda, quisiera iterar con un query sobre guideline_id y por ejemplo donde haya el valor 1, cambiarlo por 49,
2 cambiarlo por 50
3 cambiarlo por 51

y así sucesivamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo utilizan un case dentro de la consulta

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN guideline_id = 1 then 49 
WHEN guideline_id = 2 then 50
WHEN guideline_id = 3 then 51
ELSE guideline_id 
END
FROM tabla
```